# Pass a ref to a component

Tags: reactjs

I know this is probably simple but I can't seem to find the solution to this problem.  Thanks for any help

```
<InputTime
  ref={el => this.inputTimeOut = el}  // doesn't work
/>

export const InputTime = (props) => {
  return (
    <input          
      ref={props.ref}  // this doesn't seem to be working
      type={"number"}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: A ref is a reference to the component, it's not passed to the child, so it's not prop. I don't condone using refs, but in this case `this.inputTimeOut` is what you want, that being said, don't assign the same class variable to 2 different component references.

Comment: if i try to access "this.inputTimeout" in the main component by using "this.inputTimeout.value".. even if I don't pass it to the component InputTime.. I cannot read the value.  It worked before I turned it into a component though.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: @Federkun thanks found what I needed to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with refs before but let me know if this helps:

In the example below, FancyButton uses React.forwardRef to obtain the ref passed to it, and then forward it to the DOM button that it renders:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

So try:

```
const ref = React.createRef();
<InputTime
  ref={el => this.inputTimeOut = el} 
/>

export const InputTime = (props) => {
  return (
    <input          
      ref={ref}
      className="InputTime" 
      type={"number"}
    />
  );
};
```

Or something of that variation.

Link to explanation here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to this and it worked.

```
export const InputTime = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <input
    ref={ref}
    type={"number"}
  />
));
```